# How do I prevent a WebView from scaling down a rendered web page?

Tags: html, css, cocoa, webkit, webview

I'm developing a Cocoa/Obj-C application that involves a WebView (from the WebKit framework). I've noticed that this WebView presents a slightly scaled-down version of the rendered webpage. An example screenshot:

In a browser (Safari or Firefox):

[alt text http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/9824/plain.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/9824/plain.png)

In my WebView:

[alt text http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6673/picture2sa.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6673/picture2sa.png)

These happen to be local HTML/CSS files generated by the program, but if you tell the WebView to load http://www.google.com, it'll do the same thing. Both images and text seem slightly smaller. As you see, in this example, the 1px horizontal rule just disappears.

It's very important that this WebView presents an accurate picture of what the page will look like in a browser, so I would like to resolve this issue. I've looked at the WebView documentation and at all of the options in Interface Builder, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this method: `- (void)setTextSizeMultiplier:(float)multiplier`.

Comment: Shouldn't that default to 1? And, like I said, both text and images are getting scaled down. I'll give it a try, though...

Comment: Could be that the default text sizes are different for the WebView, not that they are scaled down.

Comment: Nope, I checked the default text sizes. They're correct. And like I said, the images are scaling down too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this wasn't working, but it ended up working when I set the multiplier to a value greater than 1.0. Surprisingly, it scaled the images and everything, not just text. However, this makes me wonder: 1) Why is the method named "setTextSizeMultiplier" when it is actually the entire page that gets scaled? The documentation doesn't mention this. 2) Why is the default value of 1.0 making things much smaller than they should be? The text was unreadable and my 1px horizontal rule disappeared.

Comment: On my system [myWebView setTextSizeMultiplier:1.4] fixed the overall scale, but broke some other things on the page. E.g., text inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, try changing the font size default option for the web view from 12 to 16. I believe most web browsers, including Safari, use a default font size of 16, but the default font size is set to 12 for a Cocoa web view, so everything is rendered a bit smaller.

Comment: This doesn't work, but calling setTextSizeMultiplier: with a value > 1.0 does. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of the superviews that contains your webview is being rescaled? I don't remember seeing any automatic scaling in WebKit docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like that's not it. It's just a simple WebView in an NSPanel that pops up when you click a button. I also have another WebView elsewhere that has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made the WebView web page look the same as in Safari:

```
 [[webView preferences] setDefaultFontSize:16];
```

(I did the above in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` handler, after `setMainFrameURL` call. Solution is taken [from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770363/17708). Changing WebView font size in Interface Builder didn't work for some reason.)