# Cocoa WebView font too small

Tags: cocoa, webview

When I add a WebView to my application the font size of web pages is a lot smaller than that in Safari. Is there some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You need to set the default font to 16px if you want the font size to match that of Safari. You can do this in Interface Builder.

You can also do it programmatically:

```
[[webView preferences] setDefaultFontSize:16];
```